# Assign a value from excel to a html input box through excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have some ISIN-codes from bonds in an excel sheet (column A). I would like to find the corresponding rating from the site `https://www.moodys.com`.
As this should be done on a regular basis, I would like to automate this process through Excel VBA.

The website does not use any ID's so I can't use `getElementById`.

I tried using through `getElementsByClassName`, but this does not work. Also I am not sure if the "search-widget" is the correct class name.

The Error message is:

> Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438)

```
Sub SearchBot()

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 'special object variable representing the IE browser
 
    Nbr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row - 1
 
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(100000, 6))
        .ClearContents
     End With
 
 
    For i = 1 To 1 'Nbr
 
 
        'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
        Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

         'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
        objIE.Visible = True
 
        'navigate IE to this web page (a pretty neat search engine really)
        objIE.navigate "https://www.moodys.com"
 
        'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:04"))
        'Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop Until objIE.readyState = 4
 

        objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("search-widget").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i + 1).Value


    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getElementsByClassName` method returns an array of all elements with that classname, even if that is only one element. So if you know it is the first and only element with that classname, you can use `getElementsByClassName("search-widget")(0).Value`

Furthermore, you can find the right classname by inspecting the pages html. In chrome, you can do that by right clicking the element and press "inspect". The only searchbar I saw on the site has "typeahead search-box-input left" as classname by the way.

Comment: Hello Alex, thanks for your quick reply. Indeed, if I enter objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("typeahead search-box-input left")(0).Value = "something" then it works. However, it only works if I previously manually selected this input box. If I did not do this, then nothing happens. Do you know how I should do this automatically?

Comment: And do you also know how I can press "enter" in that input box?

Comment: You can use the SendKeys function: https://www.contextures.com/excelvbasendkeys.html